# For performing MLR but my data set is very highly correlated

Tags: multiple-regression

I have to perform a normal MLR but my data set is very very highly correlated now what to
What are the best methods to adress this issue
I my final regression equation I don't want more that 3 or 4 independent variables

I tried to add reciprocal data transformation column

I tried to range scale

I tried log

In all cases my regression not improving more than 0.3

Any other very good suggestion

Comment: You can consider performing regression after dimensions reduction using PCA. The first few principal components usually capture most of the variation in the data, so you might want to use them as inputs in your MLR model. In addition, the issue of multicollinearity is eliminated due to the orthogonal PCs.